# Regional specialties in "Treason"

Tags: orson-scott-card

In Orson Scott Card's *Treason*, each area of the planet specializes in some sort of ability (e.g. the one where the protagonist is from is rapid healing).

What are all of the specialties/regions in the book?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably not a complete list, but maybe others can fill in the blanks!

- Ku Kei - Control Time (They were
  originally philospohers)
- Muellers -Regeneration (Originally geneticists)
- Anderson- Appear to be anything they wish, clouding the minds of those
  around them to their will.
  (Politicians)
- Schwartz- Form rock to
  their will, as well as take energy
  from the sun (Geologists)
- Nkumai - Physics
- Bird- Socialites
- Allison- Theology
- Britton- Historian
- Drew- Dream Interpretation
- Hanks-    Psychology
- Tellerman- Actor
- Underwood- Botanist

Answer (score 2):

There are also several regions not fully specified in the book, leaving the complex universe of the story open, as in most Card's books. 
May I add also that Bird's region was governed by women, and that abilities in some places seem to have been long lost or at least, are not "magic".